# WMI connect to ManagementScope

Tags: c#, wmi

I do some tests with C# and WMI

I wonder what is the purpose of connecting to a ManagementScope ?
In my tests there is no difference whether or not I use  "scope.Connect()" , the result is the same.

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + sServer +"\\root\\CIMV2", oConn);


//  scope.Connect() ;                   When should I use this? Code works without it....
//  if (scope.IsConnected)
//      Console.WriteLine("Scope connected");

ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT FreeSpace FROM Win32_LogicalDisk where DeviceID = 'C:'");

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
    {
    freeSpace = (ulong)m.GetPropertyValue("FreeSpace");

     Console.WriteLine (freeSpace)
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the .Net source code:

The `ManagementObjectSearcher.Get()` method calls the `Initialize` method:

```
public void Get(ManagementOperationObserver watcher)
{
    if (null == watcher)
        throw new ArgumentNullException ("watcher");

    Initialize ();
    // ... more code
}
```

and the `Initialize()` method actually confirms if the scope has been initialized correctly and connects to the scope if it hasn't:

```
private void Initialize()
{
    //If the query is not set yet we can't do it
    if (null == query)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
       //If we're not connected yet, this is the time to do it...
     lock (this)
    {
        if (null == scope)
            scope = ManagementScope._Clone(null);
    }
      lock (scope)
    {
        if (!scope.IsConnected)
            scope.Initialize();
    }
}
```

So you do not have to call the `Connect()` method yourself if you use a `ManagementSearcherObject`. However you can still access the searcher from another object and then you need to verify yourself that you connected to your management scope.

The `Connect()` method of the `ManagementScope` class however does nothing else but call the very same `Initialize()` method:

```
    public void Connect ()
    {
        Initialize ();
    }
```

You can see it [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Management/managementobjectsearcher.cs) and [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Management/managementscope.cs)